# Cross Threading issue with C# ProgressBar

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading, progress-bar

I'm creating a countdown timer that allows the user to choose a valid time, and once the countdown reaches zero, it plays a sound.

I've instantiated a timer from the `System.Timers` namespace and set its `Interval` to `1` second. I convert the user-specified time to seconds, and decrement that value by `1` every time the `Timer.Elapsed` function hits. Once it reaches zero, that means the countdown has reached zero which means it's time to play the sound.

However, whenever it doesn't reach zero, I decrement the time value by `1` and I also want to increment the `ProgressBar` by using the `progressbar.Increment` function.

Unfortunately, whenever I do this, it gives me an exception having to do with multithreading issues. I know what is wrong, but I am not sure how to fix it. Do I need to start the `timer.Elapsed` function on a new thread?

The error is:

> Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'CountdownProgress' accessed
>   from a thread other than the thread it was created on.

Also, any tips on better programming habits are welcome as well.
Many thanks!

Here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Timers;
using System.Media;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form_CDA : Form
    {
        public Form_CDA()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private bool m_CountdownActive; // declare global variables and instantiate timer.
        private bool m_Cancelled;
        public decimal seconds;
        public decimal minutes;
        public decimal hours;
        public decimal time;
        public System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer();

        private void Form_CDA_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            m_Cancelled = false;
            timer.AutoReset = false;
            timer.Interval = 0;
            m_CountdownActive = false;
            richTextBox1.Text = "Hello, please select an hour between 0 and 100, a minute between 0 and 59, and a second between 0 and 59. The countdown timer will play a sound when finished.";
            btn_Cancel.Enabled = false;
            seconds = 0;
            minutes = 0;
            hours = 0;
            time = 0;
            m_StatusBar.Text = "Program properly loaded, waiting for user input"; // initialize variables.
        }

        private void btn_SetCountdown_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            seconds = numUpDown_Seconds.Value;
            minutes = numUpDown_Minutes.Value;
            hours = numUpDown_Hours.Value;
            time = (hours * 3600) + (minutes * 60) + seconds; // calculate the total time in seconds.
            if (time != 0) // if time is not zero, start timer and set up event handler timer.elapsed.
            {
                timer.Interval = 1000;
                timer.AutoReset = true;
                timer.Start();
                timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(timer_Elapsed);
                CountdownProgress.Maximum = (int)time;
                CountdownProgress.Minimum = 0;
                CountdownProgress.Value = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                m_StatusBar.Text = "Invalid selection of times. Try again.";
                return;
            }
            DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
            dt.AddSeconds((double)time);
            Label_Countdown.Text = "Finishing time: " + dt.ToString(); // display end time to user.
            m_CountdownActive = true;
            btn_Cancel.Enabled = true;
            btn_SetCountdown.Enabled = false;
            numUpDown_Hours.Enabled = false;
            numUpDown_Minutes.Enabled = false;
            numUpDown_Seconds.Enabled = false; // disable controls.
            m_Cancelled = true;
            m_StatusBar.Text = "Timer set to " + numUpDown_Hours.Value.ToString() + " hours, " + numUpDown_Minutes.Value.ToString() + " minutes, " + numUpDown_Seconds.Value.ToString() + " seconds.";
        }

        void timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (time == 0)
            {
                m_StatusBar.Text = "Countdown Finished";
                SoundPlayer soundPlayer = new SoundPlayer(@"C:\Users\marupakuuu\Desktop\New stuff\doorbell.wav");
                soundPlayer.Play(); // play sound.
                timer.Stop();
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                time = time - 1;
                CountdownProgress.Increment(1); // exception occurs here; multithreading issues.
            }
        }

        private void btn_Cancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // if user wishes to stop the countdown to start a new one.
            m_Cancelled = true;
            m_CountdownActive = false;
            btn_SetCountdown.Enabled = true;
            numUpDown_Seconds.Value = 0;
            numUpDown_Minutes.Value = 0;
            numUpDown_Hours.Value = 0;
            numUpDown_Hours.Enabled = true;
            numUpDown_Minutes.Enabled = true;
            numUpDown_Seconds.Enabled = true;
            btn_Cancel.Enabled = false;
            m_StatusBar.Text = "Countdown cancelled";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to update GUI from another thread in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/661561/how-to-update-gui-from-another-thread-in-c)

Comment: Also, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/winforms+multithreading

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A control can only be accessed within the thread it was created. Therefore use `Invoke` to execute the given code as a delegate on the main thread, where the control (progressbar) was created.

```
void timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    if (time == 0)
    {
        m_StatusBar.Text = "Countdown Finished";
        SoundPlayer soundPlayer = new SoundPlayer(@"C:\Users\marupakuuu\Desktop\New stuff\doorbell.wav");
        soundPlayer.Play(); // play sound.
        timer.Stop();
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        time = time - 1;
        Invoke(new Action(() => CountdownProgress.Increment(1)));
    }
}
```

You may want to read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b.aspx

Comment: Thank you so much! Workin' perfectly. Currently reading the article as well. Brilliant! :)

Comment: @tf.rz However, the real question is *why* is the CountdownProgress on another thread? The WinForm Timer control runs the event on the thread the timer was created.

Comment: @pst, See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.elapsed.aspx - it says: `If the SynchronizingObject property is Nothing, the Elapsed event is raised on a ThreadPool thread.`

Comment: @ebb Good point. I was considering [System.Windows.Forms.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx), which I recommend for UI work in general...